# Are there denominations that emphasize apologetic sermons?

Tags: apologetics, denomination, sermon

Are there denominations that emphasize apologetic sermons?

Comment: Welcome to this site, Hal. If you haven't yet clicked the 'Tour' link at the bottom l.h.s. of this page, please do so soon. Apologetics can come into sermons about attitudes and behaviour, and it also comes into far more than the subject of salvation through grace.  Perhaps some of the answers given to this previous Q about Apologetics might help show the difficulty involved in trying to pigeon-hole sermons the way your Q seems to be doing. https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89651/are-there-formally-recognized-categories-of-apologetics

Comment: @Anne I don't mean to say apologetic sermons can't discuss those topics. Rather, the churches that emphasize those topics tend not to discuss them (or other topics) apologetically. In other words, sermons I've heard can either be described as advice or dogma (or a hair away from it). Are there no churches whose sermons emphasize inquiry or explanation? (In any case, I've edited the question.)

Comment: Ah, in that case I would say that in Reformed Presbyterian circles there is a stress on expository preaching; taking verses from the Bible and working through the verses, as opposed to giving 'butterfly' sermons where lots of different verses from all over the place are invoked. Expository preaching does not rule out using a few verses from elsewhere, of course, but the goal is to keep focused on the passage. Sometimes many weekly sermons may result from a few, or even one verse of scripture. And the topic may also be attitudes/behaviour, not just theology. Hope that helps.